# RemoveEventListener added by Class instance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, dom, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I am having difficulties (actually have run out of ideas) on how to remove event listener from my div-element, which is added every time I generate a new instance of Class.

```
class myClass {

myFunc () {
    const myDiv= document.querySelector('#div-1')
    myDiv.addEventListener('click', doThis, false)

   function doThis () {
   console.log('Test')
    }
   }
}
```

I have so far tried

```
myDiv.removeEventListener('click', doThis)
```

before adding a new eventListener, which I guess doesnt work, because it doesnt have a reference to the specific instance and function in question. I then tried

```
const myClicker = doThis.bind(this)
```

and then added and removed listener with myClicker variable, which also didnt work. Everytime I run

```
new myClass()
```

and click #div-1, a new listener is added and 'test' is printed not only one but many times...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the listener with

```
myDiv.addEventListener('click', doThis, false)
```

The removal must contain all the same parameter you pass onto the addListener

```
// Make sure to include the 'false' parameter
myDiv.removeEventListener('click', doThis,false)
```

source : https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Problem in your answer is that, doThis function will be called in "isolated", so except event object you cannot pass other arguments

Comment: In that case, you can just addEventListener to a "handleClick(event)" that then calls the doThis() with whatever parameters you need @Velaro